# Saving WPF Assets

Tags: wpf, xaml, assets

I am creating a WPF app where I'd like to create an Assets folder which will contain my images etc, then access them via a relative path, if possible.

Assuming my folder structure is as follows:

Application > Bin > Debug > EXE

Where should I create my Assets folder? And how would I access it from a relative path in XAML. I.e. Assests/Images/MyImage.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create Assets folder directly in Visual Studio solution, then you can access those assets this way `Assests/Images/MyImage.jpg` without problems. Don't forget to set Build action to Content.

Comment: Thanks, do I literally have to change the Build Action for each file in my app or just App.Config?

Comment: For each asset file. Don't forget to use Ctrl for multiselection, it will be easier ;-)